# C# where and select

Tags: c#, linq, select, where-clause, func

Can someone please help to explain what's happening in the following code? Many thanks! The result is meo but I don't understand how the two 'where' work in this context.

```
public class Cat {
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public Cat Where(Func<Cat,bool> cond) {
    return new Cat {
      Text = cond(this)? this.Text.ToUpper(): this.Text.ToLower()
    }; }
  }
public static class CatExtensions {
    public static T Select<T>(this Cat cat, Func<Cat,T> proj) 
      { 
         return proj(cat);
      } 
 }


var moggy = new Cat { Text = "Meo" }; 
var result = from m in moggy
   where true 
   where false 
   select m.Text;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to understand if you look at the method-chaining syntax version of that expression:

```
moggy
  .Where(m => true)     // returns new Cat { Text = "MEO" }
  .Where(m => false)    // returns new Cat { Text = "meo" }
  .Select(m => m.Text); // returns "meo"
```

Comment: The second where clause would not let the current `Cat` to pass through, would it?

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit confused. Is Where an extension method of where? Why do you use Where to look at the expression, when in the expression where(small letters) are used?

Comment: `Where` is a custom method defined in the class `Cat`. It is not the `Where` method from the .NET framework.

Comment: @user3735871 If you use `where` in a LINQ expression, it will look for a method named `Where` on the object that takes an argument of type `Func<ObjectType, bool>` and use that if it is present. That's what's happening here.

Comment: @displayName Neither of the where clauses is passing through the original `Cat`. Each one returns a new `Cat`.

Comment: @JLRishe: Oh... the method defined in the class is being called rather than LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

`from a in B where E` is considered the same as `B.Where(a => E)`.

Because of the fact that the class defines its own `Where` methods, these are used instead of those defined by Linq, as instance methods are always chosen over extension methods if available. Also those methods aren't applicable anyway.

The first returns an all uppercase MEO cat, then the second acts on that and returns an all lowers case meo cat.

The select is an extension method and applies the delegate to that last object.

Answer (score 0):

These are multple Where clauses in LINQ.

Usually this is like a simple And conditon

For example say we have a Customer Entity and we have all customers stored in a variable results and we want to get the Customer whose FirstName is **John** and LastName is **Doe**, then we would do

```
results.Where(x => (x.FirstName == "John") && (x.LasttName == "Doe"));
```

Now this piece of code can be written with 2 Where clauses like

```
results.Where(x => (x.FirstName == "John"))
       .Where(x => (x.LasttName == "Doe"));
```

Comment: That's not relevant or applicable here.